# Vue.js make row clickable for checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a list item clickable. When the item is clicked the checkbox within the list item should be enabled or disabled. However it's not working the way I expect.

I've made an example:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showNav: false,
    categories: [{name: 'test' }]
  },
  mounted() {

    this.categories.forEach((category) => {
      category.active = true;
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <nav class="navbar-dropdown w-full">
      <ul class="list-reset">
          <li class="flex justify-between items-center hover:bg-grey hover:text-white text-grey uppercase cursor-pointer p-3" v-for="category in categories" @click="category.active = !category.active">
              {{ category.name }}
              <input type="checkbox" class="shadow" v-model="category.active" @click="category.active = !category.active"/>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

When I change this:

```
categories: [{name: 'test' }]
```

to this:

```
categories: [{name: 'test', active: true }]
```

It's working. But in my application I fetch the application with an ajax and receive the category objects without an active property.

That's why I'm doing this:

```
this.categories.forEach((category) => {
      category.active = true;
    });
```

But that's obviously not working. How could I fix this?

Comment: Instead of a `v-model` on the `<input>`, have you tried binding to `value` attribute?

Comment: @DivyanthJayaraj yes but not working :(

Comment: This is an issue with `reactivity`. Vuejs can't observe a property that doesn't exist on the object (in this case) in question. Why not use the `index` of the object as the reference and compare based on the index, instead of adding an arbitrary property to the object called `active`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ohgodwhy mentioned in his comment there's an issue with the way you define a property for a `category`. I'm having a hard time explaining why exactly this doesn't work, although this is how you could do this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showNav: false,
    categories: [{
      name: 'test'
    }],
  },
  mounted() {
    this.categories = this.categories.map((category) => {
      return {
        name: 'test',
        active: true,
      };
    });
  },
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul class="list-reset">
    <li class="flex justify-between items-center hover:bg-grey hover:text-white text-grey uppercase cursor-pointer p-3" v-for="category in categories" @click="category.active = !category.active">
      {{ category.name }}
      <input type="checkbox" class="shadow" v-model="category.active" @click="category.active = !category.active" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

I would appreciate any additions or expansions on the reason why OP has this issue.